# What does a single particle in PSO for cloud scheduling represent?

Tags: cloud, cloudsim

When we say compute the new velocity and position of particle.

What does particle in cloud task scheduling represent. Does it represent a single task allocated to VM or all tasks allocated to VM's. What i want to know is whether a single particle represents a complete solution in itself or allocation of single task to a VM

Answer (score 0):

one dimensional array index represents task and its corresponding value in array called assigned vm. and then this one dimensional array called one particle

Comment: i need implementation of PSO cloud scheduling. Do you provide professional help?